# Regarding the proof that if $a \equiv b \pmod{m} $ then $f(a) \equiv f(b)\pmod {m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to follow proof of the following theorem in my book.

> **Theorem 2.2.**  Let $f$ denote a polynomial with integral coefficients. If $a \equiv b \pmod{m} $ then $f(a) \equiv f(b)\pmod {m}$.

I understand the proof fine, except for the bit I've coloured below:

> **Proof:** We can suppose $f(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... +c_{0}$ where the $c_i$
> are integers. Since $a \equiv  b (\pmod m)$ we can apply Theorem 2.1, part 4,
> repeatedly to find $a^2 \equiv b^2, a^3 \equiv b^3, \cdots, a^n \equiv 
>  b^n \pmod m$, and then
> $\color{blue}{c_ja^j \equiv c_jb^j\pmod{m}}$ and finally $c_nba^n+c_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0 \equiv  c_nb^n+c_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0$ by Theorem 2.1 part 3.

I don't understand what gives us that ${c_ja^j \equiv c_jb^j\pmod{m}}$? In fact, I'd expect that ${c_ja^j=c_jb^j\pmod{c_jm}}$ for any $c_j > 0$.

> **2.1 part 3** If $a \equiv b \pmod{m} $ and $c \equiv d \pmod{m}$ then $a+c \equiv b+d \pmod{m}$
>
> **2.1 part 4** If $a \equiv b \pmod{m} $ and $c \equiv d \pmod{m}$ then $ac \equiv bd \pmod{m}$.

Comment: $c_j \equiv c_j \pmod m$ and $a^j \equiv b^j \pmod m$ (from Theorem 2.1 part 4). Using Theorem 2.1 part 4 on these two gives the required result.

Comment: @Epiksalad Wow, thank you! It's so simple now that I see it.

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod{cm}$ is **stronger than** $a\equiv b\pmod m$. If $a-b$ is divisible by $cm$, then $a-b$ is divisible by $m$, because $cm$ is divisible by $m$.

Comment: @bof I see that too now. Thanks.

Comment: See the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) for a *rigorous* proof by induction on the degree of the polynomial (the cited proof is somewhat lacking in rigor since it handwaves the induction via ellipses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$c_j \equiv c_j \pmod m$ and $a^j \equiv b^j \pmod m$ (from Theorem 2.1 part 4). Using Theorem 2.1 part 4 on these two gives the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it, is  to say the coefficients stay the same between f(a) and f(b). $a\equiv b\bmod m\implies a=mx+b$ and powering each side leads to all but one term  divisible by m namely it leads to $a^n\equiv b^n\bmod m$ replacement then shows the coefficient need not change, so we can add them into the mix as well. by any number being congruent to itself, we get the desired result.

**ADDENDUM**:

we can also  just hide the $c_j$ in the multiplier of m, after all,  all multiples of $c_jm$ are multiples of m .

Comment: aka it's a consequence of binomial expansion termwise.